# How to correctly pipe output into "say" in terminal

Tags: terminal, command-line

I realized that the `say` command can be great when combined with another command/program because it can read you the output. I tried to pipe the output from `leave` to `say` by typing the following in terminal, but it didn't work.

```
leave +5 | say
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Based off of very initial analysis, I don't think you'll be able to, because `leave` forks/daemonizes and leaves your shell.

Comment: So you can't pipe output from daemons to another program?

Comment: You can probably capture the output of daemons and pipe it to another program, but not as simply as `|`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on mankoff's answer, this works:

```
leave +1 2>&1 | while read line ; do echo $line | say ; done
```

although leave no longer vanishes into the background and lets you carry on typing. Similarly:

```
leave +1 2>&1 | while read line ; do echo $line | say ; done &
```

will make it vanish into the background, but will also speak a (harmless) process ID number as well. So neither is quite perfect, but both work.

(I was looking for a solution to:

```
ping google.com | say
```

which suffers a similar problem, and someone suggested the above as a solution. I didn't add this as a comment to mankoff's answer because I can't work out how to put spaces and newlines in comments.).

Comment: You can't put newlines in comments. Unfortunately.

Comment: you could edit my answer, but I think your comments are worthy of their own 'answer'. To silence the process ID, perhaps something before `|say` like `|grep -v ^[0-9]*$`, etc.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'm guessing `read line` reads each line of an input and then you just echo the line so you can pipe it to `say`?

Comment: Yes, and the `while ... do` form makes sure it does the _read line/say line_ pair over and over. (The problem is that when you pipe input into `say`, it waits until the entire end of the input before speaking all of it at once, however `read` takes one line and stops. So the code chops a continuous output into line-sized chunks and launches `say` once for each chunk).

Answer (score 7):

Your example is, in general, the correct way to pipe normal output to say:

```
 cat file | say
 echo "hello world" | say
```

The specific issue is that the `|` (pipe) character transfers `STDOUT` from the command on the left to `STDIN` to the command on the right. `say` then speaks whatever is on `STDIN`.

However, `leave` does not print the output directly to `STDOUT`. It is either using `STDERR`, or some other message mechanism. You can pipe `STDERR` through the `|`, but the syntax is shell dependent. For `bash`, you would do it like so, although I'm not sure that this will make `leave` work with `say`, as I don't much about `leave`.

```
cmd 2>&1 |cmd2
```

Comment: `STDERR` or some other message mechanism? Why would it do that. Another commenter seems to think the issue is that `leave` is a daemon. What is that last command you wrote? `cmd 2>&1 |cmd2`

Comment: The last command pipes STDOUT and STDERR through the pipe. Normally only STDOUT gets captured, and STDERR goes wherever the first command would send it. Why would `leave` do that (whatever "that" is)? Because the authors wrote it that way.

Comment: I used that command to pipe `STDERR` from `leave` to `say` and it almost worked. Basically, all of the output was sent at one time rather than in increments.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to this - if you want to pipe an ongoing file to say, the "recipe" also works with tail:

```
tail -f ~/Documents/activity.log | while read line ; do echo $line | say ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply can´t use `leave` for that, rather use `sleep` with the correct amount of seconds (put it into a short script to convert seconds to minutes, hours):

```
sleep 60 && say -v Vicki 'Time to leave!' &
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution although The question was not how to make the computer say Time To leave; I want to know how to pipe output from one program to `say`. Thanks for the response though.